# Replicate S3 bucket to another S3 bucket's subpath

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have searched the documentation and can replicate one S3 bucket to another, but I cannot find how to do it to a sub folder.

Example:

```
 S3::Bucket1/* -> S3::Bucket2/Folder1/Folder2/*
```

This would cause an object at `S3::Bucket1/test_file.csv` to become `S3::Bucket2/Folder1/Folder2/test_file.csv`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Also S3 supports many lifecycle rules that you might want to look into.

Comment: I will look into the life cycle management. I need to do this as I have external sources copying real-time data to my pipeline. I am looking to consolidate these external sources into a single bucket to process S3 create events. Having each external source go to its own bucket very much complicates the gathering and processing of S3 events.

Comment: Are you wanting to 'move' the objects, or just copy them? How many new files are created each day? How big are the files?

Comment: Move or copy works. New file every ~1 min, average 5Mb. Would like lowest latency in the process as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options available.

[Amazon S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) can automatically replicate objects to another bucket, but I don't think it supports a change of directory.

The AWS CLI `aws s3 sync` command can be used to copy files and it first checks the source and destination directories so that it only copies files that are new/modified. However, if you have huge quantities of files, this checking process can take a long time.

[Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-copy-object.html) can copy objects in bulk, but you must provide a set of input names so it knows which objects to copy.

Or, you could **create your own AWS Lambda function** that copies a file to the destination. You then configure the function to be triggered whenever a new object is created in the source bucket. This will copy the file very soon after the new object appears. There are many examples of such functions on StackOverflow.

Here's some sample code for such a Lambda function:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'my-target-bucket'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Get incoming bucket and key
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    # Copy object to different bucket
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket,
        'Key': source_key
    }
    target_key = source_key # Change path here if desired

    s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(target_key).copy(copy_source, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'})
```

Comment: I am thinking the lambda might be the way I need to go.

Comment: Yes, if you simply wish to copy incoming objects to another location, it is actually the simplest method. I have added some sample code.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough rep to vote, but know that I tried!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from the console try this -

1. Select the objects you want to copy.
2. Choose the copy option from the Actions menu and then provide the path where you want to copy those objects.

If you want to move with the aws cli then the following command would help -

```
aws s3 cp s3://Bucket1/* s3://Bucket2/Folder1/Folder2/
```

I hoope this works for you!

Comment: This is great, but I am looking at using the S3 replication system since it's ongoing.